# How do you notify a PagerAdapter that the fragments have changed when the count is the same?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have built an application with a navbar on the left, whose main content is a ViewPager

The ViewPager slides between two different views.

When the user selects something from the navgation bar, I send a message to the ViewPager's adapter (I have tried both FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter for this, both won't work) which sets an internal variable and calls notifyDatasetChanged();

The problem is that the getCount() method always returns 2 , so when the adapter checks to see if the dataset has changed, it sees that the items are still 2 and does not go on to call getItem(position).

The getItem(position) returns different fragments according to the value of the internal variable that is set before notifyDatasetChanged();

I tried overriding getItemId(position) in case the pager checks for the id, but it seems to not bother after checking the count.

Is there a way to force the adapter to rebuild the fragments when notifyDatasetChanged() is called?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Edit: here is the code I am currently using:

```
public class ContentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ViewedSection _section = ViewedSection.Main;

    public ContentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ViewedScreen screen = get_screen(position);
        return screen == null ? null : FragmentFactory.GetFragment(get_screen(position));
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    private ViewedScreen get_screen(int position) {
    //code to resolve which screen will be shown according to the current position and _section
    }

    public void set_page(ViewedSection section) {
        this._section = section;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So when the user clicks on a NavBar item, I call ((ContentAdapter)_pager.getAdapter()).set_page(section);

Comment: Do you want the `ViewPager` to switch between the two views when the respective navigation drawer items are selected or change `Fragment` you added to the `PagerAdapter` and thus it should update and show the new `Fragment`?

Comment: Can you post some code, so I can better understand this problem?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have each menu item of the navigation bar load two different fragments whcih the viewpager will show, for example there is a menu item called main,that will show the MenuFragment and the SettingsFragment, when the menu item called play is selected, the pager should switch between the fragments of PlayFragment and ListFragment

Comment: I'll post my code when I get home for more clarity
I did find a...kind of weird solution,I just wanna know if there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need to override

```
    public int getItemPosition (Object object)
```

Return `POSITION_UNCHANGED` if you don't want to replace the fragment.  Return `POSITION_NONE` if you want to replace the fragment.  (Also, you can return a new position to move the fragment to.)

A common override is

```
    public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

which will just rebuild everything.